# Is there a react-native function or package for Morphing that we can apply on a photograph?

Tags: react-native

I have a question and I need to know if we can apply a morphing effect on a photograph in react native. If we can, can you help me to know how we do it and if we cannot what languages is more adapted for a mobile application?

So in fact I have to make a mobile application that allows me:

- To Take or choose pictures.
- To Define reference points between the two images.
- To Calculate the corresponding animation.
- And to Save the animation in a video or gif format.

I have already realized the classes that allows me to take a picture and to access at the gallery. (in react-native)

Answer (score 0):

Without more details is hard to answer but you could try react-native-svg. Here is a link to an example [Building React Native Animated Feedback UI](http://nobrok.com/tag/morphing/)

or reactArt [Morphing SVG Paths with React Art](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/19/Morphing-SVG-Paths-with-React-Art)

It would help if, when you ask, you gave more information though (e.g., the image format, what you have already tried, and research you have already conducted to look into the topic.)

Cheers!